# Javascript & HTML5 - button to play next video not working

Tags: javascript, button, html5-video

Thanks for stopping by.  I'm creating a page to cycle through video clips.  The cycling through part (run() function) works just fine.  I also created a few buttons to play the specific video clip and these are not working.  I've only written the function for the first button and I'll write the other two when I get the first working.

Any help if greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tommy

```
<video id="tutorials" autoplay onended="run()" 
    autobuffer="true" width="600px" height="350px" controls>
<source src="video1.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>

<br>
<br>

<button id="tut1">Play Tutorial 1</button>
<button id="tut2">Play Tutorial 2</button>
<button id="tut3">Play Tutorial 3</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    video_count =1;
    videoPlayer = document.getElementById("tutorials");

    function run()
    {
        video_count++;
        if (video_count == 4) return;
        var nextVideo = "video"+video_count+".mp4";
        videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
        videoPlayer.play();
    };

    document.getElementByID("tut1").onclick = function()
    {
        videoPlayer.stop();
        videocount = 1;
        var video = "video1.mp4";
        videoPlayer.src = video;
        videoPlayer.play();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hey Tommy, It looks like you are missing some code here. Such as videoPlayer.play(); That object and method is probably undefined. What errors are you getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to structure the code this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  video_count =1;
  videoPlayer = document.getElementById("tutorials");

  function runNext()
  {
    runVideo(video_count+1);
  }

  function runVideo(number)
  {
    if (number > 3) return;
    video_count = number;
    videoPlayer.src = "video"+video_count+".mp4";
    videoPlayer.play();
  }

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<button id="tut1" onclick="runVideo(1);">Play Tutorial 1</button>
<button id="tut2" onclick="runVideo(2);">Play Tutorial 2</button>
<button id="tut3" onclick="runVideo(3);">Play Tutorial 3</button>
```

Comment: I agree. That code definitely flows better. I had to take out the stop() for it to work, not sure why though sense I'm playing it below that... It works great though.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I think there is no `stop()` function. There's only `pause()`.

Comment: Good to know. I guess that's what I get for making assumptions.  Thanks again for your help!